# Hibernate Interceptors doesn't get called in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor

I have a simple interceptor

```
public class HistoryInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HistoryInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        LOGGER.debug("INTERCEPTOR - HERE");
        return super.onLoad(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDelete(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        LOGGER.debug("INTERCEPTOR - HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        LOGGER.debug("INTERCEPTOR - HERE");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
        LOGGER.debug("INTERCEPTOR - HERE");
        return true;
    }

}
```

that I'd like to use to update a particular field of an object just before it's persisted. This is the important part of my db-context.xml

```
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">


    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.common.model"/>

        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="com.hibernate.configs.JsonPostgreSQL9Dialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="${hibernate.default_schema}"/>
            </map>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Datasource Configuration -->
    <bean
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/config/database.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${jdbc.initialSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${jdbc.maxIdle}" />
    </bean>
```

and my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="msPU">
        <class>com.common.model.OrderLine</class>

        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor"
                      value="com.hibernate.configs.HistoryInterceptor"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

With this configurations, my interceptor is never called and I can't figure out the reason.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `hibernate.ejb.interceptor` property in the `jpaPropertyMap` instead of using the `persistence.xml` config file. It seems that the `persistence.xml` file is never used so it should fix your problem.

```
...

<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
    <map>
        <entry key="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.hibernate.configs.HistoryInterceptor" />
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="com.hibernate.configs.JsonPostgreSQL9Dialect" />
        <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}" />
        <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <entry key="hibernate.default_schema" value="${hibernate.default_schema}"/>
    </map>
</property>

...
```